# Android-ERROR: resources.apk doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

My whole project doesn't contain any mistakes... except one.

I'm making an android app using Eclipse. Everithing worked well until I tried to run my project. It says "resources.apk" doesn't exist(in bin).

What should I do? It should be written automatically. Is there a way to make Eclipse write it or something like that?

Comment: If You git not too much code, is it possible to post Your XML layout files? It is possible that there is an error, that You don´t see.

Comment: but is it possible that the resources.apk was deleted because of a xml mistake?

Comment: i've never had the same error. the resources.apk was just always there. automatically!

Comment: Try to remove lib 8n buildpath and clean ur project

Comment: if You have an error in XML, sometimes it happens that the build break the resources. please check all XML files, it is possible, but must not be the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st Eclipse menu / project / clean. Clean the project.

2 delete the bin folder within Eclipse, Eclipse will create it again.

Helped me many times.